# Select timediff between records - Negative Value

Tags: mysql, datediff

Please can someone assist. I am trying to select the time diff between two rows and get a negative time value. I need the actual difference in a positive number.

Below is my query :

```
SELECT
  id,
  Name,
  DateTime,
  TIMEDIFF(
    (SELECT MAX(DateTime) FROM alex WHERE DateTime < t.DateTime),
    DateTime
  ) AS timediff

FROM alex AS t
```

Here is a screenshot of my table:

[My Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APWxM.png)

[My Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6jlT.png)

Comment: Which 2 rows do you want the time difference from? You might need to clarify your question a bit.

Comment: Hi Johan. this is data from a time and attendance log, I need to get the time difference between each row. its currently getting the correct time but in a negative. So for instance, id 1 time 08:00, id 2 08:30, id 3, 09:00, id 4 10:30. So the time diff will be 30 mins, 30 mins, 01:30 mins etc.

Comment: The first record will not have a value. the second record will be ID 2 - ID 1 etc. ID 3 - ID 2 - ID 4 - ID3 and so on.

Comment: Here is the table 
ID count EnNo Name Mode IOMd DateTime
1  1  7  ALEX  1  0  2018-09-10 13:00:22.000000
2  1  7  ALEX  1  0  2018-09-10 13:05:55.000000
3  1  7  ALEX  1  0  2018-09-10 14:46:49.000000 
4  1  7  ALEX  1  0  2018-09-10 15:47:12.000000
5  1  7  ALEX  1  0  2018-09-10 15:57:07.000000
6  1  7  ALEX  1  0  2018-09-10 16:42:59.000000
7  1  7  ALEX  1  0  2018-09-11 07:43:58.000000
8  1  7  ALEX  1  0  2018-09-11 09:17:14.000000
9  1  7  ALEX  1  0  2018-09-11 11:36:37.000000
10  1  7  ALEX  1  0  2018-09-11 12:45:24.000000

Comment: Please update your question with this information. While it's good that you present it, it's easier to read the question when it's all in one place.

Comment: I have done so. Sorry. New to stack overflow.

Comment: No problem, we've all been new to the site :)